# Number of surjections and generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

knowing that the number of surjections $N_m\to N_n$ is (using the principle of inclusion exclusion):

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} (n-i)^m$

furthermore, we know the connection with stirling numbers:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} (n-i)^m$

Knowing this, how can I obtain the generating function of the surjections $e^x-1$ ?

Comment: What makes you think the generating function for surjections is $e^x-1$? It seems to me that $e^x-1$ is just the egf of the sequence $[0,1,1,1,\dots]$.

Comment: Seq of sets is $\mathcal{R}=SEQ(SET_{\geq 1}(Z)))$ is $\frac{1}{1-A^x}$ , $A^x=e^x-1\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{2-e^x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $(n-i)^m=m![x^m]e^{(n-i)x}$, where $[x^m]f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^m$ in the power series $f(x)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom ni(n-i)^m
&=m!\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom ni [x^m] e^{(n-i)x}
\\
&=m![x^m]\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni (e^{x})^{n-i}(-1)^i
\\
&=m![x^m](e^x-1)^n
\end{align}
This shows that the exponential generating function (e.g.f.) for surjections onto a set of size $n$ is $(e^x-1)^n$. If you instead want the e.g.f. for surjections onto a set of any size, then you need to sum over all possible $n$. In conclusion, the e.g.f for all surjections is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^x-1)^n=\frac1{1-(e^x-1)}=\frac1{2-e^x}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but how to prove $(n-i)^m=m![x^m]e^{(n-i)x}$

Comment: @LuisAlexandher Use the Taylor series for $e^{(n-i)x}$: 
$$
e^{(n-i)x}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(n-i)^mx^m}{m!}
$$